# Google Chrome extension margin/blank space insert for image

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm designing a Google Chrome extension. It is designed to insert an image into text. It currently does so, but the image attached at the bottom shows my problem. The image displays over text, and I was wondering if there was a way to make the image have its own separate space, as if I was using margin - so the snake is to the left of the logo and all of the links, and everything else on the page is shifted to the right slightly. Neither marginLeft nor marginRight work, though. This is my code:

popup.js:

```
  function imageappend() {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("imageedit_1_3932659157.png");
    img.style.position = "fixed";
    img.style.top = "0";
    img.style.left = "0";
    img.style.padding = "0";
    img.style.marginRight = "7%";
    img.style.marginLeft = "0";
    img.style.marginBottom = "0";
    img.style.marginTop = "0";
    img.style.width = "5%";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }

  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: imageappend
  });
})();
```

[image: Image spawns over text]

Answer (score 0):

There is not easy answer. It depends much by the layout of the document you inject your script into. The script is injected in the main frame or in a specific one?
If we take as model the wiki page (which it'd seems it have not frameset) you could move all body content in a new div styled with float:right and insert your image in another div (at the same level of the previous div) styling it with float:left

Something like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="csImg" style="float:left"> <img src="..." style="..."> <div>
   <div id="mainContainer" style="position:relative; float:right"> all moved body content <div>
<body>
```

There are several ways to do the same thing... ... and I'm certainly not a black belt in CSS.
Note that if you style the injected image with:
position:fixed
top:"0"
left:"0"
you'll always get an overlaid image placed in the upper left corner of the document.

Comment: popup.js is linked to popup.html, which is the main popup code for the Google Chrome extension. I don't actually have access to the body or div of the website that the extension is visiting.

Comment: I guess you inject the script into the page through the action (so in the manifest permissions section you should have "activeTab").
You can access the page because otherwise you would not have been able to insert the image. You have to access DOM nodes through CSS selectors and make some movement and restyling